# Keep only rules that replace integers with other integers

Tags: list-manipulation, core-language, filtering, rule, faq

Let's say I have a list of replacement rules:

```
List1 = {2 -> 3, b -> 5.5, 6.57 -> 2, 3 -> 4.5, 1 -> -1, 0.03 -> 0.5, 9 -> a}
```

The desired output is `{2 -> 3, 1 -> -1}`.

I have tried the following, to no avail:

```
Cases[List1, _Integer -> _Integer]

Cases[List1, IntegerQ[#[[1]]] && IntegerQ[#[[2]]] &]

Cases[List1, Rule[Integer_, Integer_]]
```

How can I obtain the desired output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can name the pattern:

```
Cases[List1, r : (_Integer -> _Integer)]
```

> {2 -> 3, 1 -> -1}

You can also wrap the pattern with `PatternSequence`

```
Cases[List1, PatternSequence[_Integer -> _Integer]]
```

> {2 -> 3, 1 -> -1}

This also works:

```
Cases[List1, _[__Integer]]
```

> {2 -> 3, 1 -> -1}

Answer (score 6):

Use [`HoldPattern`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldPattern):

```
 Cases[List1, HoldPattern[_Integer -> _Integer]]
```

> {2 -> 3, 1 -> -1}

Answer (score 5):

You could use `Verbatim`

```
Cases[List1, Verbatim[Rule][_Integer, _Integer]]
```

> {2 -> 3, 1 -> -1}